# Bidirectional Map in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, data-structures, dictionary

Cocoa provides NSDictionary, which essentially is an associative array.

Is there a nice way to get bidirectional associativity? i.e. one way would have been if NSDictionary had a `keyForObject:` method which mirrored the behavior of `objectForKey:`.

I don't really care if NSDictionary is not the way to get this. I know NSDictionary *does* provide `keysOfEntriesPassingTest:` but it returns an `NSSet *` which doesn't look very clean for the kind of thing I want to have.

Here is an example:

```
fieldMap = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"c0",@"synckey",
    @"c1",@"wi_id",
    @"c2",@"wi_parent_id",
    @"c3",@"wi_type",
    @"c4",@"wi_rh_task",
    @"c5",@"decision_key",
    @"c6",@"wi_stat",
    @"c7",@"wi_prio",
    @"c8",@"wi_cd",
    @"c9",@"wi_ct",
    @"cb",@"wi_dh_stat",
    @"cc",@"wi_user",
    nil];
```

I want to translate between *c0* and *synckey* and back, and ditto for the other fields.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [CHDataStructures](https://github.com/davedelong/CHDataStructures) framework has [CHBidirectionalDictionary](https://github.com/davedelong/CHDataStructures/blob/master/source/CHBidirectionalDictionary.m).

Comment: CHDataStructures seems to have a lot of other stuff that is useful as well. I am going to go ahead and include it.

Answer (score 10):

The closest thing for what you're after is, I believe `allKeysForObject:`.  This returns an NSArray containing the keys corresponding to all occurrences of a given object in the dictionary.  Obviously if the object is in the dictionary only once, the NSArray will contain only one object.

So with your example:

```
fieldMap = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"c0",@"synckey",
    @"c1",@"wi_id",
    @"c2",@"wi_parent_id",
    @"c3",@"wi_type",
    @"c4",@"wi_rh_task",
    @"c5",@"decision_key",
    @"c6",@"wi_stat",
    @"c7",@"wi_prio",
    @"c8",@"wi_cd",
    @"c9",@"wi_ct",
    @"cb",@"wi_dh_stat",
    @"cc",@"wi_user",
    nil];
```

This additional code would return an array containing 1 string object evaluating to @"c7":

```
NSArray *keyArray = [fieldMap allKeysForObject:@"wi_prio"];
```

[Aside: Note that this would only work here because of how the compiler works; it takes all occurences of @"wi_prio" and makes them the same object.  If instead you had perhaps loaded the dictionary from disk etc, this approach will not work for NSStrings.  Instead you should probably use `allKeys` and then iterate through them, comparing with `[mystring isEqualToString:anotherString]`.]