# How can I efficiently get the reverse mapping of a key-value in an NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I am mapping `NSString` objects to `NSNumber` objects in an `NSDictionary` in order to set `enum` types from JSON strings like this:

```
typedef enum
{
    XXEnumTypeA,
    XXEnumTypeB,
    XXEnumTypeC,
} XXEnumType;

...

@property (nonatomic, assign) XXEnumType enumType;

...

self.mapNSStringToEnumType =
@{
    @"enumTypeA" : @(XXEnumTypeA),
    @"enumTypeB" : @(XXEnumTypeB),
    @"enumTypeC" : @(XXEnumTypeC),
};

...

self.enumType = [self.mapNSStringToEnumType[stringFromJSON] integerValue];
```

Now I want to go the other way, to convert the `enum` value into the string. I don't want to store another dictionary with the reverse mapping and the solution I used involves a linear search through the mapping dictionary to find the value and then return the key.

In practice, my linear method is fine and neither performance nor memory are an issue, but I am curious from an academic point of view if there is another more efficient way I don't know about, or perhaps a different type of structure that holds the mapping both ways (ensuring all values are unique too)?

Comment: Why don't you want to store another dictionary?

Comment: If the mapping is 1:1 (mutually equivalent), then `[dict allKeysForObject:val][0]` works well.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks, that's what I'm using :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416271/bidirectional-map-in-cocoa

Comment: @Wain because actually the mapping dictionary is provided by a sub-class and I don't really want to generate the reverse-map and store it in an associated object (as it's more complex code and I like to keep it simple) and the linear-search solution is perfectly fine. The question is academic really - I guess I didn't need to go into any detail about the background and I could have just said something like "given a massive dictionary in a low memory environment such that it's slow to linear search and impractical to store a reverse-map... etc." :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something along those lines:

```
#define S(x)    #x
#define TOS(x)  @S(x)
```

and then:

```
typedef enum {
    MyEnum_01
,   MyEnum_02
} MyEnum ;

- (void) test {
    NSLog(@"%@", TOS(MyEnum_01)) ;
    NSLog(@"%@", TOS(MyEnum_02)) ;
}
```